# Are CLRegions sandboxed to the application that created them?

Tags: core-location, clregion

As in, if I create and monitor a region, does CLLocationManagerInstance.rangedRegions in another app include my region information?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed they are :-)

They also get deleted if you uninstall the app.